# How to get Array of an json Object swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to get the array from the JSON Object

Here is my Code:

```
let url = URL(string:"http://192.168.0.117/rest/login.php")
        let parameters = ["email": email , "pwd":password]
        var request = URLRequest(url : url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    if let json = json {
                        print("HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON OF LOGIN : \(json)")
                        let status = json["status"] as! String
                        let datas = json["data"] as! String
                        print("Here is the Data : \(datas)")                       
                        print("here LOIGN : \(status)")
                        if status == "200"
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dosigninEmp", sender: self)
                            }
                        } else if status == "204"
                        {
                            self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Not Authorized User")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }).resume()
```

I am getting the Output as:

```
HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON OF LOGIN : ["status": 200, "data": {
    "emp_id" = 1004;
    type = emp;
}, "Message": Auth Succesful]
```

how i can get "type" because i am getting status and using segue but now i want to fetch status as well as type to use segue and i am unable to get type 
Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: try this line to parse json :-  
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]

Comment: YOur json response is in either dict or in array, so what does semicolon is doing there??

Comment: @sohanvanani. `[String: Any]` and `Dictionary<String, Any>` is exactly the same thing.

Comment: it is in array . i am getting this response only . but in android i am getting the proper response. @dahiya_boy

Comment: @Abhijit Show me your postman screen shot for this api response bcz i don't think your response is proper. pls recheck it.

Comment: in JSONSerialization i am converting the data into array by using Options so i am getting all the response in the array @dahiya_boy

Comment: but the response in android i use to get as {"status": 200, "data": {
    "emp_id" = 1004;
    type = emp;
}, "Message": Auth Succesful}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think converting your data in json will give proper json format of string, array & dictionaries. And that's why it would give the datas in `Dictionary`:

```
print("HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON OF LOGIN : \(json)")
let status = json["status"] as! String
let datas = json["data"] as! String
print("Here is the Data : \(datas)")                       
print("here LOIGN : \(status)")
```

Can change these lines into:

```
var type = ""
var datas = [String: AnyObject]()
if let data = json["data"] as? [String: AnyObject], let typeStr = data["type"] as? String {
    datas = data
    type = typeStr
}
print("Here is the Data : \(datas)")                       
print("Here Type : \(type)")
```

Comment: @Abhijit, one more thing, perhaps you will receive `status` in `NSNumber` not in string, so to get that correct use `let status = String(json["status"] as! NSNumber)`. Hope this will help

Comment: I am getting the value of the status using string only . because the server is sending the status in string itself @Ankit

Comment: @Abhijit. Ok, thats fine.